# How is codility running time calculated?

Tags: java, performance, cumulative-sum

I am a little confused about how Codility actually calculates run-time of a submitted solution.

> For one (pretty small test case), my solution fails performance-wise, with Codility reporting it took longer than 5 seconds to complete.
> When I run a unit test with the same input (an `int[]{1,1,1}`) I always get under 200ms.

Even if my algorithm was super inefficient, it can't take 5 seconds to run on an array of three ints...

[image: My unit test result]
[image: Result from Codility]

Comment: The automatic complexity analysis may be calling your code with larger arrrays: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/48505/how-does-the-automatic-complexity-analysis-of-codility-work

Comment: The feedback from Codility says it failed on an [1,1,1] input and the Performance tests section says the code has ran >5s for all test cases. Which contradicts itself.

Answer (score 0):

look at your complexity- it's O(N**2) and not O(N). Your complexity time doesn't stands with the requirements.